# To create an authentication system

Tags: authentication, flutter

I am new in flutter and in apps. I work on a little game for the moment and I need an identifier for each member, I have a MySQL database and php script api. I have done a signup page and a signin page too.

I have no experience in app so i would like to know how game apps works exactly. I have bravolotto a lotto game application and if i remember well when you signup you Don't need to login after that. When you open the application you are automatically connected to the app.

What are the best solutions to create an authentication system in flutter.

I need to have the user id on all members page of the app so if the user play I can save the result of his game with his user id in my MySQL database with php api.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? Are you asking on how the system will know if the user is logged in or not? Like an automatic log in if the user already is logged in?

Comment: You may want to look into Firebase Authentication for managing users.

Comment: Firebase is a database no ??? I use MySQL and php for manage my users